# Why ICommandText::Execute updates the value for pRowsAffected always as -1 even though the statement is executed correctly?

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008

I try to use ICommandText::Execute to execute sql select and Insert. But it always updates the value for RowsAffected as -1 with a return value  S_OK for hr.
As I proceed to get the rows from the table for 'select statement' it is working fine and providing the correct data from the table.

1. But the Insert fails to update the data in the table with returning value S_OK with RowsAffected  value as -1 .
2. Why the 'RowsAffected' is always -1 even though the query is executed without errors for 'select statement'.

My Code Snippet:

```
IMultipleResults * multipleRowSets;
DBROWCOUNT RowsAffected= 0;

hr = pICommandText->Execute(NULL, IID_IMultipleResults, NULL, &RowsAffected, (IUnknown**) &multipleRowSets);
```

Please someone help me to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of using mIMultipleResults, IMultipleResults::GetResult can be used to get the number of rows affected by delete,update and insert.

hr = multipleRowSets->GetResult(NULL, 0, IID_IRowset, &RowsAffected, (IUnknown**) &rowset)

Here, RowsAffected returns the number of rows updated.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms723081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx